# Markup not show when loaded

Tags: autodesk-forge, markup, autodesk-viewer

I have a problem when showing the markups on my PDF viewer. The markups are not show when i load the data were saved before. I don't have any error and it seem that the markups already loaded because when i try to load it again i have a message "This layer is already loaded, will not load again.", but on my screen nothing in there ?
Please help !

```
   var _markupsExtension =viewer.getExtension("Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsCore");
        _markupsExtension.show();
        _markupsExtension.loadMarkups(data, 'layer1')
```

Comment: This is my data . Sorry i can not find the way to show the image in here, please follow the link  . https://i.imgur.com/P2O24xa.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to enter and then leave the edit mode before you could restore saved markups so try:

```
        _markupsExtension.enterEditMode();
        _markupsExtension.leaveEditMode();
        _markupsExtension.loadMarkups(data, 'layer1')
```

Comment: Hi Bryan, i figure out the problem is that my data is not enough because i'm try to save it before i draw something. Thank you very much for your answer !

Comment: And for the viewerState do you know which one need to save it to database . When i saved this state, it format as [Object object] on my database (i use SQL) , not look like what i got from this viewerState =  _markupsExtension.viewer.getState() ?                         https://i.imgur.com/LIh4IAR.png

Comment: That's because the default stringifier for object only stringifies its type info ... use `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` to serialize JSON objects.